# The pipe operator isn't working

Tags: elixir, ecto

This works well:

```
a1 = Repo.get_by(MyModel, var1: var1)   
a2 = Repo.preload(a1, [:aaa, bbb: :ccc]).items
```

But this throws an exception:

```
Repo.get_by(MyModel, var1: var1) |> Repo.preload([:aaa, bbb: :ccc]).items

# or this
# a2 = Repo.get_by(MyModel, var1: var1) |> Repo.preload([:aaa, bbb: :ccc]).items
```

being:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function MyApp.Repo.preload/1 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

      * preload/2
      * preload/3
```

What's up with it?

Answer (score 6):

Your code is currently parsed as:

```
Repo.get_by(MyModel, var1: var1) |> (Repo.preload([:aaa, bbb: :ccc]).items)
```

that is, first `Repo.preload` is called with 1 argument, then its `items` field is extracted, and then the pipe happens, which doesn't work.

You can fix this by wrapping the pipeline in brackets:

```
(Repo.get_by(MyModel, var1: var1) |> Repo.preload([:aaa, bbb: :ccc])).items
```

or use `Map.get` or `Map.fetch!` to extract the `items` key:

```
Repo.get_by(MyModel, var1: var1) |> Repo.preload([:aaa, bbb: :ccc]) |> Map.fetch!(:items)
```